# Can I get online users in Group Chat without joining the group

Tags: quickblox

If I know the Room Id of a group can I get the list of online users in that group without joining the group? like,

```
QBGroupChat currentChatRoom = 
groupChatManager.createGroupChat(groupDialog.getRoomJid());
Collection<Integer> onlineGroupUsers = null;
try {
      onlineRoomUsers = currentChatRoom.getOnlineUsers();
} catch (XMPPException e) {
}
```

Please not that I didn't join the group, just got the room id from the Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join chat to get the list of users, you just need to get the particular dialog using cycle, if you know the dialog's ID from **QB.chat.dialog.list()** 
After you found the dialog, you can get the list of its users by **occupants_ids**

To get more information, please have a look at http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Retrieve_dialogs